# jquery check if asp checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello everyone I have a checkbox I want to check if its checked or no on client side, before postback happens. 
Here is the checkbox:

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" Checked="true" ID="checkboxRules" />
```

Thanks in advance, Laziale

UPDATE:
The problem is that there is a button on the page too which is triggered by js code, and maybe I can add a line there to check if the checkbox is checked once the button is clicked, otherwise display message for unchecked checkbox:

function enterClick() {
        $('#SUBMIT').click();
    }

```
var ishown = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#BUTTON').click(function (e) {
```

//I want to put the checkbox logic here

Thanks again

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a server-side Checkbox, it will send something like `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />` as HTML to the client after ASP.NET processes the control.

The id of the checkbox isn't going to be checkboxRules as you have it in the source code. ASP.NET will make a concatenation of the server-side form id + master page id (if using a master page) + checkboxRules so in this case I won't use a selector that depends on element id.

We can make a jQuery selector as narrow as possible to only select inputs with a type of "checkbox" and with a CSS class of "checkbox".

```
$('input[type=checkbox] .checkbox').attr('checked')
```

will return the boolean value of the check status of the input. This will find any input on the page that is a checkbox with that CSS class.

Answer (score 11):

try...

```
if ($('#<%= checkboxRules.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your checkbox is the only item on the page having the checkbox class:

```
var checked = $(".checkbox").is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to your checkbox and use the 'hasClass' function jQuery provides. Like below:

```js
var isChecked = $('[data-checkbox]').hasClass('checkbox-selected');
```

```html
<asp:CheckBox data-checkbox="" Text="Some Caption" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("[id$='checkbox_ID']").prop('checked')) //Result: true or false
{
 // your code here
}
```