# Retain TextBox value when CheckBox is checked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have a set of `TextBox` that will automatically compute the 'total' based on 'gross amount' (**user input**). 
Each text box has a condition that is based on another text box.

My computation works perfectly, but I need a `CheckBox` to allow the user to decide whether to remove the 'tax' or retain it. Every time the `CheckBox` is checked, the value of the text boxes that I have became zero. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is what I have so far.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            Number.prototype.formatMoney = function (c, d, t) {
                var n = this,
                c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
                d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
                t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
                s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
                i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
                j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
                return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
            };

        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(this).keyup(function aa() {

                $("input[name='txtbx_less']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_gross = $("input[name='txtbx_gross']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_less = parseFloat(txtbx_gross) * 0.15;

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_less)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_less']").eq(index).val(txtbx_less.formatMoney());
                    }

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_net']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_gross = $("input[name='txtbx_gross']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_less = $("input[name='txtbx_less']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_net = parseFloat(txtbx_gross) - parseFloat(txtbx_less);

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_net)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_net']").eq(index).val(txtbx_net.formatMoney());
                    }

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_add']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net = $("input[name='txtbx_net']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add = parseFloat(txtbx_net) * 0.12;


                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_add)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_add']").eq(index).val(txtbx_add.formatMoney());
                    }
                    else
                        $("input[name='txtbx_add']").eq(index).val("0.00");

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_billed']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net = $("input[name='txtbx_net']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add = $("input[name='txtbx_add']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_billed = parseFloat(txtbx_net) + parseFloat(txtbx_add);

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_billed)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_billed']").eq(index).val(txtbx_billed.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });


                $("input[name='txtbx_add1']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net1 = $("input[name='txtbx_net1']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add1 = parseFloat(txtbx_net1) * 0.12;


                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_add1)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_add1']").eq(index).val(txtbx_add1.formatMoney());
                    }

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_billed1']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net1 = $("input[name='txtbx_net1']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add1 = $("input[name='txtbx_add1']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_billed1 = parseFloat(txtbx_net1) + parseFloat(txtbx_add1);

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_billed1)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_billed1']").eq(index).val(txtbx_billed1.formatMoney());
                    }
                });



            });


        });
```

**Front-end**

```
<table class = "billcomp">
  <tr>
    <td class = "prebiltd">GROSS AMOUNT :</td>                          
    <td class = "prebiltd">
      <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_gross" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
        <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999999g>.<00..99>" />
      </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "prebiltd">LESS: 15% ASF :</td>
    <td class = "prebiltd">
      <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_less" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
        <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" />
      </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "prebiltd">NET AMOUNT :</td>
    <td class = "prebiltd">
      <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_net" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
        <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" />
      </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chckbox_nonvat" Text="NON-VAT" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "prebiltd">ADD 12% VAT :</td>
    <td class = "prebiltd">                                         
      <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_add" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
        <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" />
      </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "prebiltd">BILLED AMOUNT :</td>
    <td class = "prebiltd">
      <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_billed" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
        <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" />
      </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As the first step, you can use `$('#<%= chckbox_nonvat.ClientID %>').click(function () { ... })` and write code to reset textbox values. Note: DX textbox must be assigned with their unique `ClientInstanceName` (`<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_less" ... ClientInstanceName="txtbx_less">` & set the value like this: `txtbx_less.SetText('0')`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Would you mine giving me sample based on my sample codes? Thank you. Would try your suggestion.

Comment: Which DX textboxes you want to set their value to 0 when the checkbox clicked? I need a few minutes to clarify all things before writing a sample.

Comment: The textbox for vat. Which is txtbx_add. Thank you for accommodating my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to provide client-side capability for DevExpress textbox controls you need to set `ClientInstanceName` attribute as the textbox client ID:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_add" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material" 
ClientInstanceName="txtbx_add">
...
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Since ASP.NET standard checkbox control provided in the sample doesn't specify `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute, it assumed to have pre-assigned `ClientID` so that client-side event uses checkbox `click` trigger given below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // other stuff

    // get current DX textbox value
    // this value should be stored before using checkbox click event
    var value = txtbx_add.GetText(); // or use GetValue()

    $('#<%= chckbox_nonvat.ClientID %>').click(function () { 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            txtbx_add.SetText(0); // if checked, set to 0
        } else {
            txtbx_add.SetText(value); // if unchecked, set to previous state
        }
    });

    // other stuff
}
```

NB: You can substitute `$(this).is(':checked')` to `$(".checkbox").is(':checked')` if you're sure there is only one checkbox at the page defined by `CssClass="checkbox"`.

References:

[jquery check if asp checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477959/jquery-check-if-asp-checkbox-is-checked)

[ASPxClientTextEdit.SetText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientTextEdit.SetText.method) (DevExpress Documentation)

Comment: Do I need to put Autopostback = "True" on checkbox?

Comment: `AutoPostBack=True` works for server-side events which triggers postback for corresponding event, if you want only client-side effect or not including the value during postback the attribute is unnecessary to be set.

Comment: But nothing happened. It's not working. I'd just try your codes.

Comment: Have you encountered the error in client-side code? You're trying to change the textbox value in client-side, right? Use `console.log` to watch if correct value is being set.

Comment: Sorry haven't check that I forgot to end the script. Wow it's working!!! I have another concern. How can I deduct the it from my computation?

Comment: Also the previous state if you unchecked the checkbox is not working.

Comment: The previous state `else` condition depends to your actual code, you can create a global scoped JS variable as shown in example & assign it with `txtbx_add.GetText()` or `txtbx_add.GetValue()` everytime the textbox recalculated.

Comment: Will try to do that. Thank you for the suggestion. Is it okay to comment here and ask you if I get stock again? Thank you! :)

Comment: Please ask another question linked to this question (accept the existing answer when you're satisfied with the solution) if you having another problem with fixed code. Also you can use chat as alternative.

Comment: How can I create a global variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149768/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-xtian).